# Combining embedded entities with one-to-many entities

Tags: android, android-room, entity-relationship

I have the following situation for sports:
Each match has exactly 2 teams. Each team has many players. 
Since I need to know which team is first and which second, I created entities like this:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class MatchEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val matchId: String,
    @Embedded(prefix = "firstTeam_")
    val firstTeam: TeamDetailedWithPlayers,
    @Embedded(prefix = "secondTeam_")
    val secondTeam: TeamDetailedWithPlayers,
)

data class TeamDetailedWithPlayers(
    @Embedded
    val team: TeamDetailedEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "teamId",
    )
    val players: List<PlayerEntity>
)

@Entity
data class TeamDetailedEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    /* ... */
)

@Entity
data class PlayerEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val teamId: String,
    /* ... */
)
```

Now when I try to build this, because of prefixes, I get the following error:
`` Cannot find the parent entity column `id` in TeamDetailedWithPlayers. Options: firstTeam_id, ... ``.


Is there any (other) way to elegantly solve this, without involving explicit foreign keys for teams inside `MatchEntity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are mixing what should be POJO's and what should be Entities and basically attempting to store duplicated data and store data that would need unnecessary type converters.

- if @Entity is used then it's defining a table, if not then it's a POJO

As an example Match should have a matchId and perhaps other match specific data and a reference to the first and second team as opposed to attempting to embed and duplicate the entire time info and therefore players in the match entity.

So table (Entity) you want a Match table with a reference to each of the the 2 teams , a team table and a player table with a reference to the team that player is in.

You then have POJO's such as TeamWithPlayers and MatchWithTeams. For example for the table structure (Schema) you could have :-

- **Note** id's use Longs (more efficient)
- **Note** id names are unique rather than just id ( duplicate columns can cause issues with ambiguous columns)

**TeamEntity**

```
@Entity
data class TeamEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val teamId: Long,
    val teamName: String
    /*
        other Team detail here
     */
)
```

**PlayerEntity**

```
@Entity
data class PlayerEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val playerId: Long,
    @ForeignKey(entity = TeamEntity::class,parentColumns = ["teamId"],childColumns = ["teamReference"])
    val teamReference: Long,
    val playerName: String
    /*
        other player info here
     */
)
```

**MatchEntity**

```
@Entity
data class MatchEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val matchId: Long,
    @ForeignKey(entity = TeamEntity::class, parentColumns = ["matchId"],childColumns = ["firstTeamReference"])
    val firstTeamReference: Long,
    @ForeignKey(entity = TeamEntity::class, parentColumns = ["matchId"],childColumns = ["secondTeamReference"])
    val secondTeamReference: Long
)
```

This without any POJO's would create a database that would look like (via Database Inspector) :-

[image]

- as can be seen this has compiled successfully.

You could then insert some testing data with simple Dao's and then work on the Dao's and POJO to get the data that you want.

Example POJO for Team with the list of players namely **TeamWithPlayers** :-

```
data class TeamWithPlayers(
    @Embedded
    val teamEntity: TeamEntity,
    @Relation(entity = PlayerEntity::class,parentColumn = "teamId",entityColumn = "teamReference")
    val playerlist: List<PlayerEntity>
)
```

Example POJO for Match with the 2 TeamWithPlayers :-

```
data class MatchWithTeamsWithPlayers(
    @Embedded
    val matchEntity: MatchEntity,
    @Relation(entity = TeamEntity::class, parentColumn = "firstTeamReference",entityColumn = "teamId")
    val firstTeam: List<TeamWithPlayers>,
    @Relation(entity = TeamEntity::class,parentColumn = "secondTeamReference",entityColumn = "teamId")
    val secondTeam: List<TeamWithPlayers>
)
```

**Working Example**

First the Dao's in **AllDao**

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertTeamEntity(teamEntity: TeamEntity): Long
    @Insert
    fun insertPlayerEntity(playerEntity: PlayerEntity): Long
    @Insert
    fun insertMatchEntity(matchEntity: MatchEntity): Long
    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM teamentity")
    fun getTeamCount(): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM teamentity")
    fun getAllTeamsWithPlayers(): List<TeamWithPlayers>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM matchEntity")
    fun getAllMatchesWithTeamdsWithPlayers(): List<MatchWithTeamsWithPlayers>
}
```

Next the Database **SportsDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = [TeamEntity::class,PlayerEntity::class,MatchEntity::class],version = 1)
abstract class SportsDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getDao(): AllDao
}
```

Finally testing via an Activity **MainActivity** (see comments)

- Note testing undertaken on the main thread for convenience and brevity

:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: SportsDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    val TAG = "SPORTDBINFO"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // STAGE 1 create and populate the data base using just the core schema no POJO's
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,SportsDatabase::class.java,"mysports.db")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
        dao = db.getDao()


        // Add some testing data but only if none exists (any Team row existing as the check)
        if (dao.getTeamCount() < 1) {
            
            // 3 teams
            dao.insertTeamEntity(TeamEntity(1, "Team 1"))
            dao.insertTeamEntity(TeamEntity(2, "Team 2"))
            dao.insertTeamEntity(TeamEntity(3, "Team 3"))

            // 3 players per team except team 3 with 2 playes
            dao.insertPlayerEntity(PlayerEntity(100, 1, "Player 100 in Team 1"))
            dao.insertPlayerEntity(PlayerEntity(101, 1, "Player 101 in Team 1"))
            dao.insertPlayerEntity(PlayerEntity(102, 1, "Player 102 in Team 1"))
            dao.insertPlayerEntity(PlayerEntity(200, 2, "Player 200 in Team 2"))
            dao.insertPlayerEntity(PlayerEntity(201, 2, "Player 201 in Team 2"))
            dao.insertPlayerEntity(PlayerEntity(202, 2, "Player 202 in Team 2"))
            dao.insertPlayerEntity(PlayerEntity(300, 3, "Player 300 in Team 3"))
            dao.insertPlayerEntity(PlayerEntity(301, 3, "Player 301 in Team 3"))

            // some matches each team plays each team home and away i.e. 6 matches
            dao.insertMatchEntity(MatchEntity(1000, 1, 2))
            dao.insertMatchEntity(MatchEntity(1010, 2, 3))
            dao.insertMatchEntity(MatchEntity(1020, 1, 3))
            dao.insertMatchEntity(MatchEntity(500, 3, 1))
            dao.insertMatchEntity(MatchEntity(510, 3, 2))
            dao.insertMatchEntity(MatchEntity(520, 2, 3))
        }

        // Stage 2 check the use of the TeamWithPlayers POJO using the getAllTeamWithPlayers PJOJO
        for (team: TeamWithPlayers in dao.getAllTeamsWithPlayers()) {
            logTeam( team.teamEntity)
            for (player: PlayerEntity in team.playerlist) {
                logPlayer(player)
            }
        }

        // Stage 3 check the use of the MatchWithTeamsWithPlayers POJO
        for(match: MatchWithTeamsWithPlayers in dao.getAllMatchesWithTeamdsWithPlayers()) {
            logMatch(match.matchEntity)
            // First team
            for(team: TeamWithPlayers in match.firstTeam) {
                logTeam(team.teamEntity)
                // players in the first team
                for(player: PlayerEntity in team.playerlist) {
                    logPlayer(player)
                }
            }
            // Second team
            for(team: TeamWithPlayers in match.secondTeam) {
                logTeam(team.teamEntity)
                // players in the second team
                for(player: PlayerEntity in team.playerlist) {
                    logPlayer(player)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun logPlayer(playerEntity: PlayerEntity) {
        Log.d(TAG,"\t\tPlayer Name = " + playerEntity.playerName + " PlayerID =" + playerEntity.playerId + " TeamReference = " + playerEntity.teamReference)
    }
    private fun logTeam(teamEntity: TeamEntity) {
        Log.d(TAG,"\tTeam Name =" + teamEntity.teamName + " TeamID = " + teamEntity.teamId)
    }
    private fun logMatch(matchEntity: MatchEntity) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Match ID = " + matchEntity.matchId + " Team 1 reference = " + matchEntity.firstTeamReference + " Team 2 reference = " + matchEntity.secondTeamReference)
    }
}
```

**Result**  i.e. the output to the log

```
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 1 TeamID = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 100 in Team 1 PlayerID =100 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 101 in Team 1 PlayerID =101 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 102 in Team 1 PlayerID =102 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 2 TeamID = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 200 in Team 2 PlayerID =200 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 201 in Team 2 PlayerID =201 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 202 in Team 2 PlayerID =202 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 3 TeamID = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 300 in Team 3 PlayerID =300 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.555 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 301 in Team 3 PlayerID =301 TeamReference = 3




2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO: Match ID = 500 Team 1 reference = 3 Team 2 reference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 3 TeamID = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 300 in Team 3 PlayerID =300 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 301 in Team 3 PlayerID =301 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 1 TeamID = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 100 in Team 1 PlayerID =100 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 101 in Team 1 PlayerID =101 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 102 in Team 1 PlayerID =102 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.562 D/SPORTDBINFO: Match ID = 510 Team 1 reference = 3 Team 2 reference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 3 TeamID = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 300 in Team 3 PlayerID =300 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 301 in Team 3 PlayerID =301 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 2 TeamID = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 200 in Team 2 PlayerID =200 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 201 in Team 2 PlayerID =201 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 202 in Team 2 PlayerID =202 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO: Match ID = 520 Team 1 reference = 2 Team 2 reference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 2 TeamID = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 200 in Team 2 PlayerID =200 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.563 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 201 in Team 2 PlayerID =201 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 202 in Team 2 PlayerID =202 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 3 TeamID = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 300 in Team 3 PlayerID =300 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 301 in Team 3 PlayerID =301 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO: Match ID = 1000 Team 1 reference = 1 Team 2 reference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 1 TeamID = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 100 in Team 1 PlayerID =100 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 101 in Team 1 PlayerID =101 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 102 in Team 1 PlayerID =102 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 2 TeamID = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.564 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 200 in Team 2 PlayerID =200 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 201 in Team 2 PlayerID =201 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 202 in Team 2 PlayerID =202 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO: Match ID = 1010 Team 1 reference = 2 Team 2 reference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 2 TeamID = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 200 in Team 2 PlayerID =200 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 201 in Team 2 PlayerID =201 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 202 in Team 2 PlayerID =202 TeamReference = 2
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 3 TeamID = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 300 in Team 3 PlayerID =300 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 301 in Team 3 PlayerID =301 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO: Match ID = 1020 Team 1 reference = 1 Team 2 reference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.565 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 1 TeamID = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.566 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 100 in Team 1 PlayerID =100 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.566 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 101 in Team 1 PlayerID =101 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.566 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 102 in Team 1 PlayerID =102 TeamReference = 1
2021-04-11 13:26:06.566 D/SPORTDBINFO:  Team Name =Team 3 TeamID = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.566 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 300 in Team 3 PlayerID =300 TeamReference = 3
2021-04-11 13:26:06.566 D/SPORTDBINFO:      Player Name = Player 301 in Team 3 PlayerID =301 TeamReference = 3
```

Comment: Nature of the app is such that duplication is not (really) a problem. Teams will rarely get reused and can easily be deleted, say, once a week. Therefore, I wanted to go with @Embedded as it provides a bit simpler interface. However, as it doesn't look like it's possible I went with your suggestion. Thank you!